# $.each from two object (json)

Tags: jquery, json

```js
$.each(data.bahan, function (i, v) {
    $("select.bahan_asli")
        .clone()
        .insertAfter("#bahan:last")
        .val(v.id_bahan)
        .addClass('duplicate')
        .removeClass('bahan_asli')
        .css("display", "block")
        .append("<input type='hidden' value='" + data['detail'].id_detail + "'>");  
});
```

This code does not work, what I should change `data['detail'].id_detail` to?

Comment: You should add a json example so we can help you better.

Comment: nobody can help you if you don't show what is inside your data variable.

Comment: Just guessing, but should `data['detail']` be `v['detail']`, as that's the parameter you've used in your `each()` handler.

Comment: this is my json {
 "bahan": [{
  "id_bahan": "4",
  "nm_jenis": "katun"
 }, {
  "id_bahan": "1",
  "nm_jenis": "katun"
 }, {
  "id_bahan": "3",
  "nm_jenis": "katun"
 }, {
  "id_bahan": "2",
  "nm_jenis": "spandex"
 }],
 "model": {
  "id_model": "3",
  "nm_model": "test 1708"
 },
 "detail": [{
  "id_detail": "5",
  "id_model": "3"
 }, {
  "id_detail": "6",
  "id_model": "3"
 }, {
  "id_detail": "7",
  "id_model": "3"
 }, {
  "id_detail": "8",
  "id_model": "3"
 }]
}

Comment: please answer it, its very important for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Your are iterating on data.bahan not on data. The current item is v so may be your details are in v.id_detail.

Comment: data.bahan on data, but `data['detail'].id_detail` not in same data of data.bahan

Comment: Do you construct the json or you consume it from a third party api?